# Use of string matching and arbitrary Arguments in this certain code

Tags: python

I am doing this code in which

**place_order(*item_tuple)**: This function accepts the order placed by the customer.menu is Veg Roll, Noodles, Fried Rice and Soup.The function should check whether the items requested are present in the vendor’s menu and if so, it should check whether the requested quantity is available for each by invoking the check_quantity_available() method. 
***check_quantity_available(index,quantity_requested)***: This function should check whether the requested quantity of the specified item is available. If so, it should reduce the quantity requested from the quantity available for that item and return True. Otherwise, it should return False.

```
 menu=('Veg Roll','Noodles','Fried Rice','Soup')
 quantity_available=[2,200,250,3]

 def place_order(*item_tuple):


 def check_quantity_available(index,quantity_requested):

 place_order("Veg Roll",2,"Noodles",2)
 place_order("Soup",1,"Veg Roll", 2, "Fried Rice1",1)
```

Output I expect

```
Veg Roll is  available

Noodles is  available
```

How can i get the output since i am not clear with the python code.

Comment: You don't seem to have written any actual code, so it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: can you expound your expected output for your given input? should it fail if one parameter tuple is incorrect?

Comment: Okay, Got you , Now converting it to code. :)

Comment: I am new to Python. I want to understand how to  match the string with the tuple menu. and then how to check the availability of that stock

Comment: depperm NO it should just print stock not available if the item is less than available

Answer (score 1):

```
# menu=('Veg Roll','Noodles','Fried Rice','Soup')
# quantity_available=[2,200,250,3]



menudict={"Veg Roll":2,"Noodles":200,'Fried Rice':250,'Soup':3}



def place_order(*kwargs):
    countt=len(kwargs)
    for i in range(0,countt,2):
        if(not menudict.keys().__contains__(kwargs[i])):
            print("Item "+kwargs[i]+" is not available")
        elif(menudict[kwargs[i]]<kwargs[i+1]):
            print(kwargs[i] + " stock is over")
        else:
            menudict[kwargs[i]]-=kwargs[i+1]
            print(kwargs[i]+" is available")






# def check_quantity_available(index,quantity_requested):
#  pass
place_order("Veg Roll",2,"Noodles",2)
place_order("Soup",1,"Veg Roll", 2, "Fried Rice1",1)
```

> USING DICTIONARY MAKES IT VERY EASY.

Comment: Thank you. This helps but is there a way to do it without dictionary. without *kwargs. Just with *args. Because the following structure has to be followed. Using the second function is also mandatory.

Comment: Man we have to do it this way.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you help ? I have been struggling this from past two days.

Answer (score 0):

```
menu=('Veg Roll','Noodles','Fried Rice','Soup')
quantity_available=[2,200,250,3]



def place_order(*kwargs):
    countt=len(kwargs)
    for i in range(0,countt,2):
        index=1
        if kwargs[i] not in menu:
            print("Item "+kwargs[i]+" is not available")

        elif(check_quantity_available(kwargs[i],kwargs[i+1])):
            print(kwargs[i] + " stock is over")
            index = (menu.index(kwargs[i]))
        else:
            quantity_available[index]-=kwargs[i+1]
            index = (menu.index(kwargs[i]))
            print(kwargs[i]+" is available")



def check_quantity_available(name,quantiy):
 if quantity_available[menu.index(name)]<quantiy:
     return True
 else:
     return False

place_order("Veg Roll",2,"Noodles",2)
place_order("Soup",1,"Veg Roll", 2, "Fried Rice1",1)
```